# ask about run jms program

Tags: java, jms

i dont understand what is not good and i need help with this code
so this is the code

```
package chat;

        import javax.jms.*;
        import javax.naming.*;
        import java.io.*;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.util.Properties;

        public class pub implements javax.jms.MessageListener{
            private TopicSession pubSession;
            private TopicSession subSession;
            private TopicPublisher publisher;
            private TopicConnection connection;
            private String username;

            /* Constructor. Establish JMS publisher and subscriber */
            public pub(String topicName, String username, String password)
            throws Exception {
                // Obtain a JNDI connection
                Properties env = new Properties( );
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "guest"); 
                env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory"); 
                env.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099"); 
                env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming");

                // ... specify the JNDI properties specific to the vendor

                InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext(env);


                // Look up a JMS connection factory
                TopicConnectionFactory conFactory =
                (TopicConnectionFactory)jndi.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");

                // Create a JMS connection
                TopicConnection connection =
                conFactory.createTopicConnection(username,password);





                // Create two JMS session objects
                TopicSession pubSession =
                connection.createTopicSession(false,
                                              Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                TopicSession subSession =
                connection.createTopicSession(false,
                                              Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                // Look up a JMS topic
                Topic chatTopic = (Topic)jndi.lookup("topic/testTopic");

                // Create a JMS publisher and subscriber
                TopicPublisher publisher1 = 
                    pubSession.createPublisher(chatTopic);
                TopicSubscriber subscriber = 
                    subSession.createSubscriber(chatTopic);

                // Set a JMS message listener
                subscriber.setMessageListener(this);

                // Intialize the Chat application
                set(connection, pubSession, subSession, publisher1, username);

                // Start the JMS connection; allows messages to be delivered
                connection.start( );

            }
            /* Initialize the instance variables */
            public void set(TopicConnection con, TopicSession pubSess,
                            TopicSession subSess, TopicPublisher pub, 
                            String username) {
                this.connection = con;
                this.pubSession = pubSess;
                this.subSession = subSess;
                this.publisher = pub;
                this.username = username;
            }
            /* Receive message from topic subscriber */
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                try {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    String text = textMessage.getText( );
                    System.out.println(text);
                } catch (JMSException jmse){ jmse.printStackTrace( ); }
            }
            /* Create and send message using topic publisher */
            protected void writeMessage(String text) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage message = pubSession.createTextMessage( );
                message.setText(username+" : "+text);
                publisher.publish(message);
            }
            /* Close the JMS connection */
            public void close( ) throws JMSException {
                connection.close( );
            }
            /* Run the Chat client */
            public static void main(String [] args){
                try{
                    if (args.length!=3)
                        System.out.println("Topic or username missing");

                    // args[0]=topicName; args[1]=username; args[2]=password
                    pub chat = new pub("chat","temp","111");

                    // Read from command line
                    BufferedReader commandLine = new 
                      java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                    // Loop until the word "exit" is typed
                    while(true){
                        String s = commandLine.readLine( );
                        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                            chat.close( ); // close down connection
                            System.exit(0);// exit program
                        } else 
                            chat.writeMessage(s);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace( ); }
            }
        }
```

and this is the erorr i get when i run it in eclipce:

```
 javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User: temp is NOT authenticated
        at org.jboss.mq.security.SecurityManager.authenticate(SecurityManager.java:230)
        at org.jboss.mq.security.ServerSecurityInterceptor.authenticate(ServerSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.jboss.mq.server.TracingInterceptor.authenticate(TracingInterceptor.java:613)
        at org.jboss.mq.server.JMSServerInvoker.authenticate(JMSServerInvoker.java:172)
        at org.jboss.mq.il.uil2.ServerSocketManagerHandler.handleMsg(ServerSocketManagerHandler.java:238)
        at org.jboss.mq.il.uil2.SocketManager$ReadTask.handleMsg(SocketManager.java:419)
        at org.jboss.mq.il.uil2.msgs.BaseMsg.run(BaseMsg.java:398)
        at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:756)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i am not understand if the problem emanative from the jboss connection or the code is not ok pleas i need help to run this program thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user you are attempting to access the JMS provider with is likely not permitted to access the service.

Are you sure that the username and password are correct and have been granted the correct privileges to access the provider?

Comment: i dont know i just want to run the chat from this website http://oreilly.com/catalog/javmesser/chapter/ch02.html and i insert user and pass from my mind